# Understanding module & absolute / relative package imports

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a package containing sub-folders and I would like **to include a parent module from a sub-package module**.

I have tried to follow the project structure suggested here https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/ and attempted to replicate the step-by-step procedure as listed here http://zetcode.com/lang/python/packages/ but it seems that I am missing something obvious about python's package system

Here's my project structure

```
watches/
-- ...
-- watches/
---- __init__.py (empty)
---- Logger.py
---- main.py
---- db/
------ __init__.py (empty)
------ EntryPoint.py
```

`Logger.py` contains a single class :

```
class Logger:
   ...
```

I try to import Logger.py's class and methods from `db/EntryPoint.py` as follow :

```
from watches.Logger import Logger
class EntryPoint: 
   ...
```

Then, I want to wrap-up everything in `main.py` as follow:

```
from db.EntryPoint import EntryPoint

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = EntryPoint("local")
```

and finally, when I try to execute `main.py` as follow `python3 main.py` (so I am located in `watches/watches` directory as you can guess), I guet the following error stack trace :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from db.EntryPoint import EntryPoint
  File "some/absolute/path/watches/watches/db/EntryPoint.py", line 4, in <module>
    from watches.Logger import Logger
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'watches'
```

Comment: `from ..Logger import Logger`.

Comment: You shouldn't execute a module from *within* the package itself. Try `python3 watches/main.py`. Or, potentially better, execute it as a module: `python3 -m watches.main`.

Answer (score 0):

Every import will be relative to the location where the script is being run, in your case, main.py.

So, the point of view of your program is:

```
-logger.py
-__init__.py
-db/
---__init__.pt
---EntryPoint.py
```

The program is not aware that he is an module called watches, so if you want to import the logger.py in your main, simply do:

```
from Logger import Logger
```

Or move your main to the parent folder.